# Getting feedback from a hall sensor with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

This is my first Raspberry Pi project and I'm a Python newb.

I've got a geared motor + driver + separate power supply (for the geared motor) + hall sensor.

I know the "physics" and the way everything is working for itself. But now I want to control it with my Raspberry. My goal is to use the hall sensor to count the revolutions from my geared motor using a magnet.

So every time my motor does a full turn, the magnet "hits" the hall sensor once.

My question is: What is the best way (using Python) to get "feedback" from the pin that is connected to my hall sensor?

I want to use this "feedback" to count revolutions and say: stop (or do something else) after you've hit the hall sensor 10 times.

Comment: First of all, i want to thank you both for the fast help. Based on my Post/Question i want to ask, if you can tell my which kind of reading/books you would suggest to get more into Python, especially into Python-GPIO. My biggest problem is that i have no clue, how the Python Scheme has to look like when you work with more than one module. Example: Push "Start Button" -> Motor starts -> Motor works until hit Sensor -> Motor Stops and so on..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did an experiment using a Hall sensor with magnets connected to a motor shaft.

Detail and code are available at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=632413

You should be able to connect the sensor direct to a GPIO if it has a open collector output.  Use the internal pull-up on the GPIO to 3V3.  The GPIO will normally read high but will read low when pulsed by the Hall sensor.  Just count the pulses.

The following code will show the pulses.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import pigpio

#
# OH3144E or equivalent Hall effect sensor
#
# Pin 1 - 5V
# Pin 2 - Ground
# Pin 3 - gpio (here P1-8, gpio 14, TXD is used)
#
# The internal gpio pull-up is enabled so that the sensor
# normally reads high.  It reads low when a magnet is close.
#

HALL=14

pi = pigpio.pi() # connect to local Pi

pi.set_mode(HALL, pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_pull_up_down(HALL, pigpio.PUD_UP)

start = time.time()

while (time.time() - start) < 60:
   print("Hall = {}".format(pi.read(HALL)))
   time.sleep(0.2)

pi.stop()
```

To actually count the pulses I would suggest the use of callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

[*Edit - this answer is wrong per the comments and my explanation below. I did track down several other instances on SE of an identical approach, which are also presumably wrong. It may be helpful to leave this here to prevent others making the same mistake.*]

[Matt](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/author/matt/) from [raspberrypispy.co.uk](http://raspberrypi-spy.co.uk) posted a [simple tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/09/how-to-use-a-hall-effect-sensor-with-the-raspberry-pi/) using a Pi, a Hall sensor and Python. The tutorial includes a [link to his Python code](https://bitbucket.org/MattHawkinsUK/rpispy-misc/raw/master/python/hall.py). The code's a little long to post in full, but the gist of it is:

- Set the pin connected to the sensor as an input:

  ```
  GPIO.setup(17 , GPIO.IN)
  ```
- Create events for GPIO.RISING and GPIO.FALLING on the sensor pin to detect transitions from low to high, and high to low (i.e. magnet moving into detection range and back out again):

  ```
  GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=sensorCallback1)
  ```
- Do whatever 'work' you want to do in the event handler methods (increment a counter, if count == 10 (stop or do something else))

  ```
  def sensorCallback1(channel):
    # Called if sensor output goes LOW
    timestamp = time.time()
    stamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    print "Sensor LOW " + stamp
  ```

EDIT:

I took a look over the [source code](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO) for Rpi.GPIO (specifically `py_gpio.c` -> `static PyObject *py_add_event_detect(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwargs)` and `event_gpio.c` -> `int add_edge_detect(unsigned int gpio, unsigned int edge, int bouncetime)`). The code contains a check for existing events registered against a specified GPIO pin, and returns an error message if multiple events are registered against the pin:

> Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel

Deleting either the GPIO.FALLING or GPIO.RISING event and the accompanying callback from the [article's linked code sample](https://bitbucket.org/MattHawkinsUK/rpispy-misc/raw/master/python/hall.py) corrects the issue, but restricts edge detection to one state or the other rather than both simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think that linked code can work.  I believe RPi.GPIO only allows one event detect per GPIO.

Comment: joan is right - One event detect per GPIO

Comment: +1 for both joan and Badu - my answer's rubbish, and will teach me to verify code samples more thoroughly. Just going to edit in an amendment and see if I can't attract some downvotes.

Comment: It's not that bad!  The answer is still useful as you could have a single event detect for both edges using GPIO.BOTH.  In practice it's simpler just to check one edge anyhow, I'd personally just go for a falling edge which would be triggered at the start of the pulse.